# spark-submit missing command line arugments

Tags: scala, apache-spark

in Scala + Spark, I use spark-submit to run a job with arugments. when tried to print out argument, args.foreach(println), it will skip "PROD" and only output "/tmp" and "A-1" .

Any ideas ? Thanks

```
spark-submit \
--class "com.Main" \
--master yarn-client \
--num-executors 4 \
--driver-memory 16g \
--executor-cores 10 \
--executor-memory 6g \
--jars main.jar PROD /tmp A-1 2>&1 | tee ./log
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `--jars` flag you said to spark you want to transfer `main.jar` to your cluster (I assume `main.jar` is your spark application).

> When using `spark-submit`, the application jar **along with any jars
>   included with the --jars option** will be automatically transferred to
>   the cluster. URLs supplied after --jars must be separated by commas.

Spark probably assumed `PROD` as your application so he skipped this arg.

Try this instead:

```
spark-submit \
--class "com.Main" \
--master yarn-client \
--num-executors 4 \
--driver-memory 16g \
--executor-cores 10 \
--executor-memory 6g \
main.jar PROD /tmp A-1 2>&1 | tee ./log
```

if you have still problems with arguments (weird characters like slash, pipeline ...) you can try to use quotes:  `main.jar PROD "/tmp" "A-1 2>&1 | tee ./log"`, and in `main` it should be:

```
args(0) -- PROD
args(1) -- /tmp
args(2) -- A-1 2>&1 | tee ./log
```